# Distributed System sqlite error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've recently completed a project that involves multiple different solutions communicating with each other. When I tested the project on my own network and computer it works fine. However when I use the project on a work network, the solutions don't communicate with each other properly.

My server displays the following message.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.84.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' 
or one of its dependencies.An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This on another computer? or on your own developement computer?

Comment: Yes, this is on a different compuer.

Comment: And you have made sure that folder read-write permissions are set properly so that user on PC1 can access the folder on PC2 and vice-versa?

Comment: You might want to include some parts of your code, which would make it easier to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Then You Have to install The `SQLite .NET Connector` also on the other computer, The application Works when you have installed the `.Net SQLite Connector` on your developement computer, so Make sure to install it and set the `System.Data.SQLite` CopyLocal property to true

```
<bin>\App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable assembly)
<bin>\App.dll (optional, managed-only application library assembly)
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly)
<bin>\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
<bin>\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)
```

[READ THIS !](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

> Good Luck

Comment: I think the issue is something to do with versioning? I've been reading lots of posts about 32bit and 64 bit confilicting with each other.

Comment: @Anon - it could be.  Is the other system the same OS bit version (i.e., if your local machine a 64 bit OS and the other machine 64 bit, or are they different)?

Comment: At this stage I'm not trying to run the program across two different computers. I'm simply on my work network and work computer running a program I created at home on my home computer.
This is why I think it's a versioning issue.

Answer (score 0):

This generally means you are running as a 32-bit (x86) process and trying to load the x64 SQLite interop assembly. Or vice versa.

If your app is built with AnyCPU as the build option, it is possible that a dependency is forcing it to run as a 32-bit process on an x64 machine, or more likely that you actually are running on a 32-bit OS and your code is trying to load the wrong interop.

The easiest way to solve this is to create an x86 and x64 build and deploy accordingly. There are other ways to dynamically load the proper interop assembly and a number of search engine results that can help you with that.